# FileNotFoundException JFleChooser and FileReader JAVA

Tags: java, swing, java-io, filenotfoundexception

I've been writing a code that takes a file's absolute path from a JFileChooser and uses it to read it through a BufferedReader.

This is the code:

```
    package TestPackage;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
    import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    /**
     *
     * @author MRx
     */
    public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form MainFrame */
    public MainFrame() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

File f;
String filename;
JFileChooser chooser;

private void openModelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
// TODO add your handling code here:
    chooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TEXT FILES", "txt", "text");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    filename = f.getAbsolutePath();

}                                         

private void btnRunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
// TODO add your handling code here:
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, filename);
{

public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public String readSpecification() {
        String spec = "";

        // trying to read from file the specification...
        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(line!=null) {
                spec += line + "\n";
                line = reader.readLine();
            }        
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return spec;
    }



    String modelSpec = readSpecification();
```

i think that the problem is that the reader cannot find the path because it should be written as "C:\Users\MRx\Desktop", but  the code `filename = f.getAbsolutePath();`
returns the path like "C:\Users\Mrx\Desktop..
Do you have any ideas? thanks for helping

EDIT: these are the exceptions caught:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:116)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
at TestPackage.MainFrame.readSpecification(MainFrame.java:333)
at TestPackage.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:349)
at TestPackage.MainFrame$8.run(MainFrame.java:323)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:672)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:633)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:631)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:642)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: This could never compile, please post the relevant pieces of the code you actually use.

Comment: `C:\Users\MRx\Desktop` is a directory, you cannot open it as if it was a regular file. What are you trying to do?

Comment: these are the relevant pieces. I think the problem is in here, in the OpenModel method and readSpecification method. new FileReader cannot find the file I chose in the openModelActionPerformed method.

Comment: Edited: f.getSelectedFile() and getAbsolutePath() returns me (i.e. C:\Users\MRx\Destop\sample.txt"

Comment: 1) `new FileReader(filename)` would best be.. `new FileReader(f)` 2) *"..these are the relevant pieces. I think the problem is in here"* What you think might be wrong, and most people won't look closely at a problem without runnable code. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I tried to put new FileReader(file) instead of FileReader(filename) but a NullPointerException is caught

Comment: Are you sure `filename` gets assigned **before** you call `readSpecification`?

Comment: `} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }` should be (at least) `} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();
                }`

Comment: Yes, because I tried tu put a JOptionPane.showMessage(filename) and returns me the path of the file

Comment: Use JSR 203; at least the exception will have some meaning. [`FileNotFoundException` is useless](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks#FileNotFoundException.2C_oh_my).

Answer (score 1):

**Update** You are invoking the `readSpecification` method when the object is constructed, that is before you have chosen a file. Move the line

```
String modelSpec = readSpecification();
```

into the `openModelActionPerformed` method.

---

**Old answer based on incomplete information** 
The message of `FileNotFoundException` should include the name of the file that was not found. Since it's not there, the program must be using the empty string `""` as the file name, which also happens to be the default value you gave for the `filename` variable. This suggests that you may be using a local variable for this assignment:

```
filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
```

Make sure that you use the right variable.

To verify, check which file you're trying to open before opening:

```
System.out.println("Trying to open ["+filename+"]");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
```

Comment: With JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(filename), i get the dir path as "C:\Users\Mrx\Destop\sample.txt", so the variable filename actually gets the absolutedPath of the chosen file. but, still, if I return the variable spec, the String is empty.

Comment: Please update the question with the code you actually use.